# Auto Code Completion on Eclipse Kepler for Omnifaces o:importConstants

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, enums, omnifaces

Omnifaces have this usefull feature to import enums and constants in JSF views:
http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/importConstants

I have a big enum with constants representing answers for a quiz, so is  worth have auto complete on that enum.

Someone know how to enable Eclipse auto completion in a JSF view from a enum imported by o:importConstant?, like any other atribute in a basic Managed Bean.

Comment: Just a comment, but I feel JSF in general should provide richer metadata so IDEs can do more with "unknown" libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, this requires a custom Eclipse plugin which recognizes the `<o:importConstants>` tag and prepopulates the autocomplete menu. As of now, no such plugin exist and there are as far as I know no plans (at least not from our side) for writing IDE specific plugins for OmniFaces tags/components.

I must however admit that it's interesting to have a plugin for the very purpose. This kind of autocomplete support is by the way also missing on EL 3.0 builtin "import constants" feature.